# Finding if the limit exist.

Tags: calculus, limits

I need help with this question,

Let f(x) be a function that: $$\frac1x -1 \leq f(x) \leq \frac1x $$

Find if the following limit exist:

$$\lim_{x\to {\ 0}}xf(x) $$

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have for $x > 0$ $$x (\frac{1}{x} - 1) = 1 - x \leq x f(x) \leq x \frac{1}{x} = 1.$$
We have the same inequality (just $\geq$ instead of $\leq$) for $x < 0$. Now taking the limit everywhere yields
$$1 \leq \lim_{x \to 0} xf(x) \leq 1.$$
By the sandwich theorem we have $\lim_{x \to 0} xf(x) = 1$.

Comment: This seems to be true only if you assume x>0.

Comment: OK, in the other case simply the signs change direction and become $\geq$  but it's still true that the limit is 1. You need to write this though, I think, for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Thanks, i added a small note.

Comment: The only theorem we learned in class was the squeeze theorem, could you use that in this question?

Comment: I think, what you call squeeze theorem is what i call sandwich theorem.

Comment: yeah it is, thanks for the answer :D